# C# dynamic object, modify properties based on string paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

The use case is pretty simple in concept. I receive a json payload that has two properties on the root level:

1. `instructions`
2. `base`

Instructions are set of instructions that I am supposed to apply on the base json object.

For eg - according to the below payload,

- I am supposed to traverse to the widgets within `defaultWidgets` of the base property.
- Then replace it completely with whatever is the value of `patchedValue`.

**Input Payload:**

```json
{
    "instructions": [
        {
            "patchedPath": "defaultWidget.widgets",
            "patchedValue": false,
        }
    ],
    "base": {
        "defaultWidget": {
            "hash": "ktocle2l0u527",
            "layout": "6|6",
            "managerId": "defaultWidget",
            "widgets": [
                {
                    "managerId": "defaultWidget",
                    "widgetId": "invCreateWid7",
                    "type": "standard",
                    "manifestPath": "nexxe.standard-section@0.0.0-next.11",
                    "defaultInputManifestPath": "nexxe.input@0.0.1-alpha.49",
                    "title": "scannedInvoice",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "tom"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hash": "ktocle2lrgps9",
                    "directives": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**The result should be :**

```json
{    
    "base": {
        "defaultWidget": {
            "hash": "ktocle2l0u527",
            "layout": "6|6",
            "managerId": "defaultWidget",
            "widgets": false
        }
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
var stringPayload = "{    \"instructions\": [        {            \"patchedPath\": \"defaultWidget.widgets\",            \"patchedValue\": false,        }    ],    \"base\": {        \"defaultWidget\": {            \"hash\": \"ktocle2l0u527\",            \"layout\": \"6|6\",            \"managerId\": \"defaultWidget\",            \"widgets\": [                {                    \"managerId\": \"defaultWidget\",                    \"widgetId\": \"invCreateWid7\",                    \"type\": \"standard\",                    \"manifestPath\": \"nexxe.standard-section@0.0.0-next.11\",                    \"defaultInputManifestPath\": \"nexxe.input@0.0.1-alpha.49\",                    \"title\": \"scannedInvoice\",                    \"children\": [                        {                            \"name\": \"tom\"                        }                    ],                    \"hash\": \"ktocle2lrgps9\",                    \"directives\": \"\"                }            ]        }    }}";
var parsedPayload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringPayload);
var baseJ = parsedPayload.GetType().GetProperty("instructions").GetValue(parsedPayload, null);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedPayload);
```

**I am stuck on the very initial steps , I am getting:**

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

> System.Type.GetProperty(...) returned null.

**This is what QuickWatch says:**

[image]

Comment: for parsedPayload -- what are you deserializing into? It looks like you are just pushing it into an object, which has no defined properties

Comment: If you want to change the value of `widgets`,you can convert json to JObject,and use `arsedPayload["base"]["defaultWidget"]["widgets"] =false` to change the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's returned by `DeserializeObject` in this case is `JObject` so to start with you can cast to it:

```
var parsedPayload = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringPayload);
```

Then grab instructions and target to change:

```
var instructions = (JArray) parsedPayload["instructions"]; // cast to JArray
var result = parsedPayload["base"];
```

Then we can go over instructions and apply them:

```
foreach (var instruction in instructions) {
    // grab target path and value
    var targetPath = (string) ((JValue)instruction["patchedPath"]).Value;
    var targetValue = (JValue)instruction["patchedValue"];
    // temp variable to traverse the path
    var target = result;
    foreach (var part in targetPath.Split('.')) {
        target = target[part];
    }
    // replace the value
    target.Replace(targetValue);
}
```

Now result contains what was in base with instructions applied.

Comment: I had tried something similar but it did not work because I had declared target variable as `JObject` and it failed when path reached an array. I thought I need JObject for objects and JArray for array objects.

Answer (score 2):

With Json.NET you can do that like this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var instructions = (JArray)semiParsedJson["instructions"];
var @base = semiParsedJson["base"];

foreach (var instruction in instructions)
{
    var path = (string)instruction["patchedPath"];
    var newValue = (string)instruction["patchedValue"];
    var toBeReplaced = @base.SelectToken(path);
    toBeReplaced.Replace(newValue);              
}
```

- `JObject.Parse` parses the json string
- With the index operator `[]` we retrieve the two top level nodes. - One of them is an array (that's why there is an explicit `JArray` cast)
- The other one is a `JToken`
- We iterate through the array and retrieve the `path` and the `newvalue`
- We use the `SelectToken` to get the desired node and then apply the replacement via the `Replace` method.

---

Please bear in mind that this solution is not bulletproof. You might need to change the indexer operator to [`TryGetValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm) to be able to check existence before you perform any operation on the `JToken`.

You also need to check that the `patchedPath` is valid at all.